# Is there an equivalent java constant for go's MaxUint64

Tags: java, go, math, integer, constants

go has the constant MaxUint32, for insigned integers, but does Java have an equivalent constant? Cuz I noticed that `MaxUint32` is 4294967295 and `Integer.MAX_VALUE` is 2x that.

What would be the java equivalent of

```
r := float64(stringHash(source)) / (float64(math.MaxUint32) + 1)
```

What's the difference between a float in Java and a float64 in go?

Comment: You mean that `Integer.MAX_VALUE` is *half* `MaxUint32`. Can you think why that is, given that Java `int`s are signed? It might help to look at those values in hexadecimal. A java `float` is a 32 bit floating point number. A `double` is 64 bits.

Comment: `float` in java is 4 bytes, `double` in java is 8 bytes, `float64` in go. The equivalent of `
MaxUint32` is `-1` (false sign) or as long `0xFF_FF_FF_FFL`.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this Question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6878590/642706) on Stack Overflow, `MaxUint32` is a constant for the maximum 32-bit number available within in the Go type system, ranging from 0 to 4,294,967,295.

As for Java, I can explain that **Java has only signed numeric types**. As [commented by tgdavies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73117981/is-there-an-equivalent-java-constant-for-gos-maxuint64/73118487#comment129138464_73117981), that means the largest signed 32-bit integer in Java is *half* that of the unsigned 32-bit integer in Go: 2,147,483,647. As a workaround for compatibility with Go, just us a 64-bit `long` in Java to accommodate values coming in from Go.

In recent years a facility was added to address numbers as if unsigned. But I believe that should be used only on an exceptional basis. See [*Declaring an unsigned int in Java*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9854166/642706), especially [this Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9854205/642706).

And I can quote from [The Java Tutorials](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html), provided free-of-cost by Oracle corp, which you should read before posting here on basic Java matters:

> The eight primitive data types supported by the Java programming language are:
>
> `byte`: The `byte` data type is an 8-bit signed two's complement integer. It has a minimum value of -128 and a maximum value of 127 (inclusive). The byte data type can be useful for saving memory in large arrays, where the memory savings actually matters. They can also be used in place of `int` where their limits help to clarify your code; the fact that a variable's range is limited can serve as a form of documentation.
>
> `short`: The `short` data type is a 16-bit signed two's complement integer. It has a minimum value of -32,768 and a maximum value of 32,767 (inclusive). As with `byte`, the same guidelines apply: you can use a short to save memory in large arrays, in situations where the memory savings actually matters.
>
> `int`: By default, the `int` data type is a 32-bit signed two's complement integer, which has a minimum value of -2<sup>31</sup> and a maximum value of 2<sup>31</sup>-1. In Java SE 8 and later, you can use the `int` data type to represent an unsigned 32-bit integer, which has a minimum value of 0 and a maximum value of 2<sup>32</sup>-1. Use the `Integer` class to use int data type as an unsigned integer. See the section *The Number Classes* for more information. Static methods like `compareUnsigned`, `divideUnsigned` etc have been added to the `Integer` class to support the arithmetic operations for unsigned integers.
>
> `long`: The `long` data type is a 64-bit two's complement integer. The signed `long` has a minimum value of -2<sup>63</sup> and a maximum value of 2<sup>63</sup>-1. In Java SE 8 and later, you can use the long data type to represent an unsigned 64-bit long, which has a minimum value of 0 and a maximum value of 2<sup>64</sup>-1. Use this data type when you need a range of values wider than those provided by `int`. The `Long` class also contains methods like `compareUnsigned`, `divideUnsigned` etc to support arithmetic operations for unsigned `long`.
>
> `float`: The `float` data type is a single-precision 32-bit IEEE 754 floating point. Its range of values is beyond the scope of this discussion, but is specified in the Floating-Point Types, Formats, and Values section of the Java Language Specification. As with the recommendations for byte and short, use a float (instead of double) if you need to save memory in large arrays of floating point numbers. This data type should never be used for precise values, such as currency. For that, you will need to use the java.math.BigDecimal class instead. Numbers and Strings covers BigDecimal and other useful classes provided by the Java platform.
>
> `double`: The `double` data type is a double-precision 64-bit IEEE 754 floating point. Its range of values is beyond the scope of this discussion, but is specified in the Floating-Point Types, Formats, and Values section of the Java Language Specification. For decimal values, this data type is generally the default choice. As mentioned above, this data type should never be used for precise values, such as currency.
>
> `boolean`: The `boolean` data type has only two possible values: true and false. Use this data type for simple flags that track true/false conditions. This data type represents one bit of information, but its "size" isn't something that's precisely defined.
>
> `char`: The `char` data type is a single 16-bit Unicode character. It has a minimum value of '\u0000' (or 0) and a maximum value of '\uffff' (or 65,535 inclusive).

That last one, `char`, is legacy, and should generally be avoided in favor of using [code point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_point) integer numbers.

All of those primitive types have wrapper classes, when you need an object.

For extra large integers, use [`BigInteger`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/math/BigInteger.html) class.

For extra large/small fractional numbers, use `BigDecimal`. Also use [`BigDecimal`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/math/BigDecimal.html) when you need [accuracy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating-point_arithmetic#Accuracy_problems) rather than speed-of-execution. Uses cases include fractional money matters.